# sql server 2008 foreign key on delete set default not working

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am testing different foreign key on delete options. I tired cascade, no action, set null, all works, except set default. SQL SERVER just reports error:

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_child_parent". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Test_parent", column 'no'.
The statement has been terminated.

```
create table Test_parent(
    [no] int primary key    
)

CREATE TABLE test_child(
     SUB1 INT,
    [NO] int DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT FK_child_parent REFERENCES Test_parent([no]) ON DELETE set default
)

insert into Test_parent values(1),(2)

insert into test_child values(1, 1)
insert into test_child values(2, 1)

delete from Test_parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete your parent table, which triggers the set default in the child. The DB tries to set the child records to their default `0`. But there's no `0` record in the parent table, triggering the foreign key violation.

Comment: Then what's the point of setting default?  I thought it would act like set null but would set the column to some default value. Can you make an example where set default makes sense?

Comment: if you had a '0' record in your parent table, then that'd be a proper default. e.g. consider an inventory system. if you delete a category, the products in that category can't just vanish - they still exist. so you set up a permanent "default" category, e.g. id=0, so that when you do delete the "bad christmas gifts" category, grandma's ugly sweater will go into the "default" category instead.